# I found a way to make chapter references work for me, but it must be wrong, or at least incomplete

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, biber

I am using TeXworks Verion 0.67 and MiKTeX 22.8.28 to write a a book.

I have managed to create reference that are listed at the end of each chapter, however, the way I have to do this seems wrong.

At the end of each chapter file, I have the lines:

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,title={Chapter Subject References}]
```

---

In my book's main latex file, I have these two lines. Note one is commented out.

```
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

From a clean directory, I can run pdflatex, which creates a .bcf file.

Then I can run biber, to compile the references.

Then I can go back and run pdflatex again. However, I get references at the end of each chapter that are all numbers with the text "[0]".

If I uncomment the first line with "backend=bibtex" and comment out the second line with "backend=biber", and run pdflatex again, the references are all numbered properly.

After that, I can again comment out the line with "backend=bibtex", and uncomment the line "backend=biber" and rebuild repeatedly, and my references for each chapter come out correctly numbered.

Am I really using biber for the references? I don't fully understand how this works.

Mostly I want to know what I have to change to both use biber and to get just the set of citations done with \cite{some_bib_key} in a chapter to show up properly without having to change my main tex file.

---

This is the contents of my main book file. I've changed my name, the bib file name, and each of the chapter file names to hide what the book is about.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\title{BookName}
\author{FirstName LastName}
\date{today}
\usepackage[width=6.5in, height=9.0in, top=1.0in, papersize={8.5in,11.0in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
%
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}
%
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{refsection=chapter,giveninits=true,backref=true,backrefstyle=two,block=space,defernumbers=true}

\makeindex
%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0in}
\renewcommand{\footruleskip}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt} % space for the rule
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
}
% Allowing inline font change.
\newcommand\finline[3][]{\begin{myfont}[#1]{#2}#3\end{myfont}}%

% Environement for the new font.
\newenvironment{myfont}[2][]{\csname#2\endcsname[#1]}{}

\newcommand{\Alpine}[1][]{\fontfamily{Alpine}#1\selectfont}
%
\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
%
\setlength\parindent{20pt}
\parskip 0.05in
\raggedbottom
%
\newcounter{figureNumber}
\setcounter{figureNumber}{0}
%
\newcounter{tableNumber}
\setcounter{tableNumber}{0}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\definecolor{ltgray}{gray}{0.90}

%
\chapter*{\Huge \center \vspace{-1.5cm}BookName\newline\finline[\fontsize{18}{24}]{Alpine}{\textbf{Some subsitle text}}}
\thispagestyle{empty}
% Add the image to the title page.
\ThisCenterWallPaper{1.0}{coverimage.png}

\section*{\vspace*{\fill} \huge \center by FirstName LastName}
\newpage
\subsection*{\center \normalsize Copyright \copyright 2023 FirstName LastName}
\subsection*{\center \normalsize All rights reserved.}
\subsection*{\center \normalsize 1st edition}
%\subsection*{\center \normalsize ISBN \dots}
%\subsection*{\center \normalsize \dots Publications}
%
\chapter*{\center \normalsize Dedication about the book.}
%
\tableofcontents
%
\mainmatter
%
\include{my_book_introduction}

\include{chapter_one}

\include{chapter_two}

\include{chapter_three}

\include{chapter_four}

\include{chapter_five}

\include{chapter_six}
a
\include{chapter_seven}

\include{chapter_eight}

\backmatter
\printindex
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: What happens if, rather than commenting that line and uncommenting the `bibtex` line, you just compile (yet) again without changing anything?

Comment: If you still have trouble, can you edit your code so we can compile it, removing stuff not needed to demonstrate the problem? Right now, only you can compile your code because we don't have the files it requires.

Comment: A document with `defernumbers` has to be compiled with at least LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX. This is the recommended sequence anyway, but with `defernumbers` the two LaTeX runs after the Biber run are required, since only one LaTeX run will result in only 0s. There should have been a warning about this in the `.log` file. Sometimes `defernumbers` can get stuck, in which case it is useful to delete the `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf` files and rerun the whole LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX cycle. It should not be necessary to do that anytime you change your document, though.

Comment: Thank you barbara beeton. -----

cfr - If I uncomment that yet again, the references appear correct. I think I need the line with biber though when I run biber.

I can get the references in each chapter to work. Perhaps I can run biber with the bibtex line uncommented. I recall having troubler earlier though, and that's just the procedure where I was finally successful.  -----

moewe - I know that, and that's what I do. My issue has to do with the references being numbered. Without doing what I wrote, I get references that are all numbered "[0]".

Comment: I resolved this - sort of.

I can leave the line with "backend=biber" uncommented permanently, as shown in the example.

I have to run PDFLatex twice.

Then I have to run Biber twice.

And, then I have to run PDFLatex THREE times and the third time, the reference numbers appear.

That's an okay solution.